# Multiple conditions using element in df matching a colname in lookup table to merge 3 dataframes

Tags: r, merge, cross-reference

I have three large dataframes and I want to append some of the elements from one onto another based on several criteria. I looked up similar questions in Stack Overflow but they don't seem to work for my dataframe format (or I'm not skilled enough to adapt it properly).

What needs to happen is:

1. Filter by sex in maindf1
2. Search for the same ID value in maindf1 in a rowname (first column) in maledflookup
3. Also search for the right age strata from a row in maindf1 in the *column name* of maledflookup
4. Add a new column of data to maindf1 row with matching ID that has the population value for that sex and age strata taken from maledflookup
5. Repeat with femaledflookup
6. End result is maindf1 having a population value for every row that was matched by sex, ID, and age strata

I had no luck in writing successful code as I'm not very experienced with coding in R yet. I tried some for & if loops and failed at adapting fuzzyjoin code for this task. I appreciate your help!

Example data:

```
ID<- c("12345", "NA", "NA", "44444", "99999", "11111" )
sex <- c("female", "male", "male", "male", "female", "male")
agegrp <- c("pop_0to4", "pop_70to74", "pop_25to29", "pop_70to74","pop_70to74","pop_25to29")
maindf1 <- data.frame(ID, sex, agegrp)

ID<- c("12345", "23456", "12225", "44444", "99999", "11111" )
pop_0to4 <- c("2000", "1300", "900", "737", "289", "120")
pop_70to74 <- c("25", "222", "52", "160", "100", "80")
pop_25to29 <- c("3000", "2500", "102", "1777", "3390", "2450")
maledflookup<- data.frame(ID, pop_0to4, pop_25to29, pop_70to74)

ID<- c("12345", "23456", "12225", "44444", "99999", "11111" )
pop_0to4 <- c("1111", "2333", "999", "888", "222", "122")
pop_70to74 <- c("18", "333", "66", "300", "90", "99")
pop_25to29 <- c("3333", "2555", "111", "2777", "3311", "2121")
femaledflookup <- data.frame(ID, pop_0to4, pop_25to29, pop_70to74)
```

Data and lookup tables look like (with 2000 rows):

```
#maindf1
#ID    #sex     #agegrp
12345   female  pop_0to4        
NA      male    pop_70to74      
NA      male    pop_25to29      
44444   male    pop_70to74      
99999   female  pop_70to74      
11111   male    pop_25to29

#maledflookup
#ID    #pop_0to4  #pop_25to29   #pop_70to74
12345   2000       3000         25  
23456   1300       2500         222 
12225   900        102          52  
44444   737        1777         160 
99999   289        3390         100 
11111   120        2450         80

#femaledflookup
#ID    #pop_0to4  #pop_25to29   #pop_70to74
12345   1111        3333         18 
23456   2333        2555        333 
12225   999         111          66 
44444   888         2777        300 
99999   222         3311         90 
11111   122         2121         99
```

Desired outcome:

```
#maindf1
#ID    #sex    #agegrp       #population
12345   female  pop_0to4        1111        
NA      male    pop_70to74      NA
NA      male    pop_25to29      NA
44444   male    pop_70to74      160 
99999   female  pop_70to74      90  
11111   male    pop_25to29      2450
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `left_join` from tidyverse and a properly formatted lookup table:

```r
library(tidyverse)

.maledflookup <- maledflookup %>%
  gather(-ZCTA, key = agegrp, value = censuspop) %>%
  mutate(sex = "male")

.femaledflookup <- femaledflookup %>%
  gather(-ZCTA, key = agegrp, value = censuspop) %>%
  mutate(sex = "female")

.lookup <- bind_rows(.maledflookup, .femaledflookup)

left_join(maindf1, .lookup, by = c("sex", "ZCTA", "agegrp"))
```

1. Pivot the male data using `gather` to get a dataframe with the columns `ZCTA`, `agegrp`, and `censuspop`. Also add a new column for the sex.
2. Repeat for female data
3. Concatenate male and female data using `bind_rows`
4. Join lookup table using `ZCTA`, `agegrp`, and `sex`.